# How can I get this random complex job done ? C#

Tags: c#, .net, random

I have to do a software, and it's really complex, I mean, really don't know how to get it done. There are lot of details, but I will write here a simple example of what I need.

1. The user inputs a number of words.
2. The user inputs a folder
3. The programs job:

The folder is always changed! In that folder I have files in this way:

File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
File4.txt

In the files (all same structure). It's like file1.txt:

word1
word2
word..
wordn

Maybe File1.txt has 100 words, and File2.txt only 10.

If the words that the user inputs is 10. The software has to go through as much files as possible, and get 10 words out of them.

Forgot to mention, the 10 words, should not be from the beginning of each line.

If the file1.txt is :

word1 word2 word3 word 4 word5

I would like to get the word3 outta of it. Or word2, doesn't matter but it has to be random.

The ideea is to randomize the process as soon as possible. In this case it would be cool if I could get 1 word from File1.txt 1 word from File4.txt 2 words from File2.txt and 1 word from File3.txt

How could I randomize this stuff to go in this way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: well, I didn't tried much in this cause, because don't really know how to start.

Comment: Do you know how to read from files?  Do you know how to generate random numbers?  Which specific aspects of this problem are causing you to get stuck?

Comment: I know how to read from file, I know how to generate random numbers. I don't know how to make the software in that way, to get words from as much files as possible.

Comment: I just edited the post. The words from the files have to be choosen random too.

Comment: What is the correlation between the 10 words the user inputs and the 10 words he gets back out.  Is it just 1 for 1?

Comment: Homework? Interview question?

Comment: from where are the files? is the first word == file name or select from dropdown or randomize or for each session a new file? Have the user only 1 folder? or for for each session a new folder?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

Read required files.
Copy and split words from each file into an array.
Select n random words from that array.

There are probably many ways to tackle this, but the above is very simple. Research each part of what I have listed, and you should find yourself able to complete the problem as a whole.  If a problem seems too big; divide and conquer!

Answer (score 1):

A very good way of doing what you want is the following, which is a general way to get some software up and running fast:

As soon as possible try to see what interfaces you want in your application
(i.e. what are the borders of your application, what comes into your application
and what shall go out of your application).

Then, if abstracted some interface, provide a random implementation of that
interface, which simply does what you expect. (e.g. if you want to have some
source of Data, you can have a ISomeDataSource, which has a method ReadAll, and
you can very fast provide a RandomSomeDataSource, which has a ReadAll that
returns some Data.

That way, you can get your hands on that complex problem quite fast, are
flexible to change and you see what you get. As soon as your "simple path"
is working, you can implement all those interfaces, which by then have 
a good chance of being testable and your overall application can also
be inspected by the productowner very fast, i.e. he can say what he wants
when he sees what he gets. (working really good)

**Concrete**

Have an interface for InputWords, lets call it

```
interface IWordInput
{
    void ReadWords(string[] words);
}
```

and a folder input

```
interface IFolderInput
{ 
    void InputFolder(string path);
}
```

and a random word source

```
interface IWordSource
{
    void ReadAllWords(string path, out string[] words);
    string GetRandomWord(string[] words);
}
```

and here it comes:

```
 class RandomWordSource : IWordSource
 {
     public ReadAllWords(string path, out string[] words)
     {
         // somewhat like
         words = new[] string;
         words.Add("word1");
         words.Add("word2);

         // and so on
     }

     public string GetRandomWord(string[] words)
     {
          // sic
          return words.FirstOrDefault();
     }
```